# Math task, convert 10 star rating to up and downvotes

Tags: php, wordpress, math

i want to change my articles rating-script from 10 stars rating (gdsr) to up and downvotes (like youtube).

But i dont want to loose my current ratings, so my idea is to convert the current (10 stars gdStarRating) to up and downvotes.

My problem is the math formula ... i dont get it.

**for example**

```
10 members has voted, the rating is 9
= 9 upvotes and 1 downvote
```

another example

```
18 member has voted, the rating is 9.6
=  ?? upvotes and ?? downvotes
```

or

```
15 member has voted, the rating is 8.8
=  ?? upvotes and ?? downvotes
```

What is the correct (PHP) math formula ?

Comment: You can not convert the scale of 10 to just 2 in exact way. You have, probably, to decide, that everything above 5 is up and below is down. What initial info do you have? Only average and number of voters of exact details about each vote?

Comment: There is no correct forumula for this. For example a rating could be 7.1 and had 10 votes. All 10 of those people could have voted 5 or above. Or 5 of those people could've voted like a 10, and another 5 like a 4. And anything inbetween.Why change to less info? The average rating is better in my opinion.

Comment: In my understanding a positive star rating always translates to an up-vote . For what ever purpose trying to convert a positive star rating into up-vote and down-vote seems wrong . You would need to capture up-vote and down-vote separately unless you think : well who cares !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the rating ratio by the # of total votes to get the up/down ratio that's closest to your current vote/10 ratio

i.e.

```
18 member has voted, the rating is 9.6
=  ?? upvotes and ?? downvotes
```

a rating of 9.6 translates into 96% upvotes, 18 * 96% = 17.23 => 17 up votes 1 down vote

```
15 member has voted, the rating is 8.8
=  ?? upvotes and ?? downvotes
```

a rating of 8.8 translates into 88% upvotes, 15 * 88% = 13.2 => 13 up votes 2 down votes

PHP example

```
$totalvotes = 18;
$rating = 9.6;
$upvotes = round($totalvotes * ($rating/10));
$downvotes = $totalvotes - $upvotes;
```